# Oracle: Random ACL errors

Tags: oracle, acl

I'm experiencing random ACL errors in several different Oracle databases. Some web requests issued via utl_http are just blocked with an ACL exception. The weird thing is, that all other requests around that time work just as expected.

Is there a way to use the system tables to find out, if the ACL has been changed around a specific time and what session id did it? Has anyone else experienced this behavior? I'm struggling to find any pattern. It just doesn't work once and then the next second it works again. It's not happening very often either. Just at random times once or twice a week. My colleagues swear that they didn't manipulate the ACLs but I want to "trust but verify" in this case.

Here's the message: ORA-24247: Netzwerkzugriff von Access Control-Liste (ACL) abgelehnt

Translation: Network access denied by access control list (ACL)

Comment: Probably only in the audit trail. It might be helpful to include the exception you get. Maybe your ACLs are against IPs and your requests are hostnames, and there's a mismatch or a host with multiple IPs or a temporary name resolution issue? Are you on RAC and seeing the issue only on one node? (can't think why, just something to check!) Are you always connected as the same user? Are you opening too many connections at once? (again not sure that's a thing...)

Comment: Please post the errors. have you looked in DBA_NETWORK_ACLS, DBA_NETWORK_ACL_PRIVILEGES and USER_NETWORK_ACL_PRIVILEGES .  I always run a test at the "lowest" level first to rule out a network/firewall issue.  login to the server (not the database) and try sending a curl request to the same url and see if that at least works.

Comment: You can look up [ora-24247](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-24247) tagged questions besides what OldProgrammer recommends.

Comment: @AlexPoole, we are not on a RAC, it's happening on different servers and different databases. We only have one schema that handles all http requests, the packages all run under AUTHID DEFINER. The ACL for that user grants a wildcard to ports 80 and 443. I don't yet know how many connections are opened at once. I wouldn't expect any ACL issues in this case though, but I should check just to be sure. OldProgrammer: The ACL tables look fine to me. My Problem is, that these errors are in a log somewhere without a stacktrace. I'll see what I can find out.

Comment: Same issue here. Suddenly random ORA-24247 without any pattern at all. My gut feeling it's related to some other network error but returns falsely this one.